# where does for loop ends in python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

If I got this code example:

```
for s,d in grid_values(grid).items():
    if d in digits and not assign(values, s, d):
        return False ## (Fail if we can't assign d to square s.)
return values
```

How can I know where the for ends? Because as far as I know, you could write all this down in 1 line.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Comment: You couldn't write all this down in one line. Nesting block in a block within a single line is not allowed by Python syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop ends at the end of `grid_values(grid).items()` OR if `d in digits and not assign(values, s, d)`: if `d` is in `digits` and the function `assign(values, s, d)` returns `False`.

This happens because a `return` statement stops a function, so the loop (which must be in a function because it has `returns`) is forced to break since the function is ended.

Answer (score 6):

The for loop ends at the line where the indentation drops back to the same level or lower as the `for` statement.

In your example, that is at the `return values` statement.

The loop will also be terminated when the `if` statement becomes True and the `return False` statement is executed; the function returns 'early' at that point and the rest of the loop is ignored.

As written, you cannot reduce the code to one line, as you cannot combine multiple compound statements (statement that take a indented block of code) on one line. You can reduce this to two lines with an `any()` function call with a generator expression, replacing the `for` statement, but I don't think it improves readability:

```
if any(not assign(values, s, d) for s, d in grid_values(grid).items() if d in digits):
    return False
return values
```

You could then cram all *that* into one line with a conditional expression to ruin readability some more:

```
return False if any(not assign(values, s, d) for s, d in grid_values(grid).items() if d in digits) else values
```

Don't do that..